# Almost sure convergence of infinite sum of powers of two of Bernoulli

Tags: probability

I am self teaching probability, and would like to follow up on this thread:
[Distribution of infinite sum of Bernoulli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570573/distribution-of-infinite-sum-of-bernoulli)

I understand that the distribution of $S_n$ is a uniform distribution. I'm now working on:

Show that the sequence $S_n$ converges almost surely as n → ∞ [Hint: Cauchy sequences converge]. What is the distribution of the limit S?

I believe that the sequence $S_n$ converges almost surely to 1? However, I struggle with proving almost sure convergence, so please can someone provide a proof? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have not said what $S_n$ is and the linked question talks about $Y_n$ and its *distribution* converging to a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: > I believe that the sequence $S_n$ converges almost surely to 1?

If its distribution tends to a uniform, then that cannot be true.